# Can I pluralize compound proper nouns, like "Aunts Jane" for two aunts with the same name?

Tags: proper-nouns, irregular-plurals

If I have an aunt named Jane, then I would write "Aunt Jane," where "Aunt" is capitalized because it is part of a proper noun.

If I have two aunts that are named Jane, would I write "Aunts Jane" when referring to the two of them collectively?

Comment: Not sweet to the ear. Maybe "I have two aunts named Jane. Both ..."

Comment: I'd write "two Aunt Janes".

Comment: 'The Brothers Grimm' is a fixed expression, as is 'the Brothers Karamazov', but 'the Beverley Sisters' / 'the Marx Brothers' shows more recent usage. Admittedly, 'Aunt Jane' includes an arguable honorific; certainly 'Aunt Sally' is a compound titling. But 'two Uncles Sam'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it mostly depends on where you want to use this. If it's for formal or professional writing, I'd avoid it. For most other types of writing I don't think it's an issue. I know of no hard rule on this, and as another user pointed out there are some popular instances such as "the brothers Grimm".

As this is an uncommon usage I'd make sure to use some clarifying language just to ensure there isn't unnecessary confusion. There is definitely a chance some readers might just assume a printing/typing error and continue without questioning it.

Example:

> She was looking forward to seeing her Aunts Jane again. Aunts, because
> both were named Jane, though their looks couldn't be more different.

Answer (score 1):

### Pluralize the name

Searching COCA, I found no examples of `aunts NAME` (it returned results like "Aunts Ida and Sue"). What I did find was hits for the name being plural, as in the book [Buffalo Wings](https://books.google.com/books?id=UvNpQIYVYvYC&pg=PA83&dq=%22two%20aunt%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQsOW86fiCAxVRjYkEHeycDfI4FBC7BXoECAkQBw#v=onepage&q=%22two%20aunt%22&f=false):

> As I have mentioned, I had two Aunt Bettys and loved them both dearly: Aunt Betty Hobbie (married to Uncle Tom) and Aunt Betty Craig (my father's sister), married to Uncle Bob
> Craig.

Comment: You can't say the same grammar apples without any justiification. For example, consider brother. Two brothers with the same last name would be called "the brothers Karamazov, the brothers Grimm, etc. But  there's really only one"Aunt Jemima," even though she's portrayed by various people, so you shouldn't pluralize "aunt" in this case.

Comment: @PeterShor Better? One of them isn't addressed as "Brother Grimm" so it's not directly comparable. (Now I did find an example with the religious title where it was pluralized "Brother NAMEs".)

Comment: @PeterShor If you had a reunion of all the actors who portrayed Auntie Mame, you would describe them as "all the Auntie Mames".